# What does this allowed_html setting mean?

Tags: 8

`allowed_html: <a href hreflang title id target rel class="">` I copied this from the settings of the `filter_html` plugin in a filter format config entity. I am intrigued by the `class=""` part. I looked at both `FilterHtml::getHTMLRestrictions` processing this and `FilterAPITest` and I found 
a test for `'allowed_html' => '<a> <b class> <c class="*"> <d class="foo bar-* *">'` but not `class=""`. So how is `class=""` different from just `class` or `class="*"` or omitting `class` altogether?

Comment: Class should not be empty, that's all.

Comment: Do you mean this configuration is invalid? Or that `<a class="foobar">` is accepted in the editor but `<a class="">` isn't? How is that different from `class="*"`? So confusing...

Comment: I don't see why this has close votes.  Question could use a little editing for posterity, but it is a valid and interesting question and perfectly clear to me and could have a nice answer to help users in the future.